# How can I prevent the OTA update for Google Glass?

Tags: google-glass, google-mirror-api, google-gdk

With the bad surprises the XE16 update to the Google Glass has brought (such as removing the video calls feature or removing applications I had installed), I'm wondering if there is a way to prevent an OTA update?

I don't want to root the unit (and void my warranty) and I know I could try to avoid having the battery fully charged while on wifi connection... but that's too risky and not very efficient.

At least I would like to say "no not now please" or something like that. :)

thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, do not think there is any straight way to do this right now.

Comment: Besides disabling wifi when charging in there is not a known way to prevent it from updating. It will warn you "10 seconds to updating to software release" and give you that moment to opt out

Answer (score 2):

The only way is to unlock your bootloader and/or root your device and you'll no longer receive OTA updates !

Comment: are you saying that simply unlocking the bootloader will prevent OTA updates?

Answer (score 1):

There is no current way to inhibit upgrade of Google Glass software. For the explorer program, the over-the-air updates are a feature of this program (however painful it is). [Opinion: The benefit is that candidate GlassWare will have to be updated to be useful, rather than splinter development efforts even before the product is released to the public.]

Answer (score 0):

Before plugging in to charge, always disable WiFi.  This might prevent any OTA updates.  Not suggesting you do this, but it might work.  Sounds like updates happen even if not connected to WiFi despite some older Glass documentation.

Comment: I'm not convinced this would work - I didn't have Glass set up for WiFi at my work location (due to extra auth.), and Glass still installed the update while I was at work and my device was charging.

Comment: That evidence definitely contradicts my assumption.  This substantiates your claim, from the XE12 release notes: ** It's made especially for XE12, so you'll want to plug in Glass to your charger and upgrade before downloading the app if you haven't already. ** (no mention of WiFi) - https://support.google.com/glass/answer/4353446?hl=en&ref_topic=3284656 ... I'll consider deleting my answer, thank you

Comment: I agree the docs haven't been clear - I was surprised to see it update w/o WiFi.  Reading the following, one could still assume that WiFi is necessary for the install- https://support.google.com/glass/answer/3226482?hl=en

Comment: Just got the 16.2 update at my work location without being connected to WiFi as well (and, the update actually occurred when I was on my lunch break, outside my office - so apparently you don't need to be tethered via Bluetooth either for the install to start).

Comment: I don't think it would work as it may download the update while on wifi, then start to install it only when plugged in even if there is no network connection.